# Reformat a date contained in a string with Python by removing unnecessary white space (e.g.: "1 . J U L Y 1 9 0 0" to "1. JULY 1900")

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I have multiple strings which contain dates formatted with unnecessary white space. Examples:

- "1 . J U L Y 1 9 5 0"
- "1 8 . A P R I L 1 9 8 0"
- "Hello world, today is: 2 4 . J A N U A R Y 2 0 0 0"
- "D E C I S I O N: 1 3 . D E C E M B E R 2 0 1 8 / P U B L I S H E D: 1 4 . D E C E M B E R 2 0 1 8" (edit)

Using Python 3.10, how can I replace these dates with a correctly formatted version:

- "1. JULY 1950"
- "18. APRIL 1980"
- "Hello world, today is: 24. JANUARY 2000"
- "D E C I S I O N: 13. DECEMBER 2018 / P U B L I S H E D: 14. DECEMBER 2018" (edit)

I have regex to find the dates but I am unsure how to proceed from here:

```
^\s*\d+\s+[\S\s]*\s+\d{1}\s*\d{1}\s*\d{1}\s*\d{1}\s*$
```

Comment: Three passes: s = `re.sub('(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[0-9])', ' ', s.replace(' ','').replace('.','. '))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex should match two parts to be replaced:

- `(?<=\d) (?=[\.\d\/])`: spaces that are found between two digits, or a digit and a dot
- `(?<=[A-Z]) (?=[A-Z])`: spaces that are found between two letters

Here's the full regex:

```
(?<=\d) (?=[\.\d])|(?<=[A-Z]) (?=[A-Z]):
```

Your Python code should look like this:

```
import re

your_strings = [
    "1 . J U L Y 1 9 5 0",
    "1 8 . A P R I L 1 9 8 0",
    "Hello world, today is: 2 4 . J A N U A R Y 2 0 0 0"
]

pattern = r"(?<=\d) (?=[\.\d])|(?<=[A-Z]) (?=[A-Z])"

[re.sub(pattern, '', string) for string in your_strings]
```

Output:

```
['1. JULY 1950', 
 '18. APRIL 1980', 
 'Hello world, today is: 24. JANUARY 2000', 
 'DECISION: 13. DECEMBER 2018 / PUBLISHED: 14. DECEMBER 2018']
```

Check the Regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/n7xH7a/1) and Python [demo](https://www.online-python.com/8F20ThsLgt).

Comment: This is an elegant solution and answers my question, thank you very much. On the real dataset it produces good results most of the time but it is too extensive for certain strings where other parts match up. Do you see a way to further limit the scope of the pattern, e.g. by setting the order of occurence: spaces between digits followed by spaces between two letters followed by spaces between digits?

Comment: Can you update your post with the related examples that fail?

Comment: Here is a string from the dataset: ""D E C I S I O N: 1 3 . D E C E M B E R 2 0 1 8 / P U B L I S H E D: 1 4 . D E C E M B E R 2 0 1 8". --> Output: "DECISION:13. DECEMBER 2018/PUBLISHED:14. DECEMBER 2018". The white space for all other characters except the date would ideally be conserved.

Comment: I have updated my question accordingly.

Comment: Check the updated answer. Does it work for you?

Comment: Thanks so much but any other white space outside of the date would ideally be conserved and not removed. That means that the white space around the backslash as well as for the words "D E C I S I O N" and "P U B L I S H E D" would remain in place.

Comment: No you can't, unless you match specific months, as Wiktor did it in his answer. If the percentage of your misses is too much, I'd recommend you to not use this solution. This wants to be fast and direct to catch most cases. Exceptions shall be dealt separately.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```py
import re
pattern = re.compile(r"(\d(?:\s?\d)?\s?\.)\s?((?:j\s?a\s?n|f\s?e\s?b\s?r)\s?u\s?a\s?r\s?y|m\s?a\s?(?:r\s?c\s?h|y)|a\s?p\s?r\s?i\s?l|j\s?u\s?(?:n\s?e|l\s?y)|a\s?u\s?g\s?u\s?s\s?t|o\s?c\s?t\s?o\s?b\s?e\s?r|(?:s\s?e\s?p\s?t|n\s?o\s?v|d\s?e\s?c)e\s?m\s?b\s?e\s?r)\s?(\d\s?\d\s?\d\s?\d)", re.I)
strs = ["1 . J U L Y 1 9 5 0", "1 8 . A P R I L 1 9 8 0", "Hello world, today is: 2 4 . J A N U A R Y 2 0 0 0"]

for text in strs:
    print(re.sub(pattern, lambda x: f'{"".join(x.group(1).split())} {"".join(x.group(2).split())} {"".join(x.group(3).split())}', text))
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/cORlYU).

Output:

```
1. JULY 1950
18. APRIL 1980
Hello world, today is: 24. JANUARY 2000
```

*Details*:

- `(\d(?:\s?\d)?\s?\.)` - Group 1: day, one or two digits with a dot
- `\s?` - an optional whitespace
- `((?:j\s?a\s?n|f\s?e\s?b\s?r)\s?u\s?a\s?r\s?y|m\s?a\s?(?:r\s?c\s?h|y)|a\s?p\s?r\s?i\s?l|j\s?u\s?(?:n\s?e|l\s?y)|a\s?u\s?g\s?u\s?s\s?t|o\s?c\s?t\s?o\s?b\s?e\s?r|(?:s\s?e\s?p\s?t|n\s?o\s?v|d\s?e\s?c)e\s?m\s?b\s?e\s?r)` - a month pattern
- `\s?` - an optional whitespace
- `(\d\s?\d\s?\d\s?\d)` - a year pattern, four digits.